# How to use if statement into foreach in razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to use two if statement into foreach such as this but in second if statement get error.Please advice

```
            @{
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageEdit"];
        int i = 0;
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model.PhotoTables)
            {
                if (i < 1)
                { <div class="row">
                    }


                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-wrapper">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <img src="@Url.Content(path+item.PhotoName)" alt="" />
                            <img class="delimg" src="~/Content/Adminex/images/delete-icons.png" id="@item.Id" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if (i < 1 )
                    {
                </div>}
</div>

                i++;
            }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you tried `@if (i<1 )` on the second if, as you are moving from html to razor?

Comment: Yes I used :Parser Error Message: The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Comment: It appears you are using bootstrap, and based on your code you'll have `col-xs-2` that will be outside of a `row` which is technically invalid for bootstrap..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra closing div with no matching start tag.

Your code block can contain all of the logic. Try:

```
    @{
        string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageEdit"];
        int i = 0;

        foreach ( var item in Model.PhotoTables )
        {
            if ( i < 1 )
            {
                <div class="row">
            }

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-wrapper">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img src="@Url.Content(path + item.Name)" alt="" />
                    <img class="delimg" src="~/Content/Adminex/images/delete-icons.png" id="@item.Id" />
                </div>
            </div>

            @if (i < 1 )
            {
                </div>
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
```

You only need the @ symbol on the containing codeblock.

The @ symbol is not required when you directly nest actual code blocks (not HTML), so the first `foreach`, and `if` are ok, but then we go into HTML, and then back to code for the second `if` -  we need to use a @.

Comment: In this case error solved but second if don't  work and display in page such as text.

Comment: I should have explained more, and I've edited answer accordingly... The @ symbol is not required when you directly nest actual code blocks (not HTML), so the first "foreach", and "if" are ok, but after we go into HTML again we need to use @, so the second "if" needs one.

Answer (score 0):

Manually manipulating a variable inside a `foreach` statement *can possibly lead to trouble*.  Instead, take advantage of current framework method `Select()`.

Model:

```
    var model = new SampleViewModel
        {
            Items = new List<string>
            {
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Razor:

```
    @foreach(var item in Model.Items
      .Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }))
    {
        if ( item.Index < 1 )
        {
            <div class="row">
        }

        <div>@item.Index @item.Value</div>

        if ( item.Index < 1 )
        {
            </div>
        }
    }
```

Results:

> 0 A
>
> 1 B
>
> 2 C

[DotNetFiddle MVC Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ch60yI)

Comment: Thanks for your example, but your fiddle does not contain the razor you show here, and when trying it in fiddle, it does not work...

Comment: @Christophe I just checked the link, it's exactly the same Razor code and it works for me, even after manually rerunning it.  Last Run: 8:28:00 am, Compile: 0.344s, Execute: 0.016s, Memory: 188.04kb, CPU: 0.031s

Comment: I don't know why, but is working now, sorry.